# Where do the electrons and protons formed from biological reactions go?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, proteins

In a reaction like [disulphide bond formation](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Disulfide-bond.png) protons and electrons are released. These particles are presumably damaging in high levels. What systems are in place to prevent a build up of electrons and protons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

I've reproduced the diagram that you linked to. It shows the oxidation of a pair of thiols to create a disulphide. What is missing from this scheme is the accompanying oxidising agent. So for example this could be carried out without catalysis in a reaction with molecular oxygen, in which case hydrogen peroxide would be formed. So the electrons and protons have ended up on the oxygen.

In a biological system this oxidation would usually be carried out by an enzyme, in which case the oxidising agent would probably be [FAD (flavin adenine dinucleotide)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavin_adenine_dinucleotide) or [NAD<sup>+</sup>(nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide). These are by far the most commonly used redox cofactors. In a typical eukaryotic cell these would end up either (a) being reduced either by the [mitochondrial electron transport chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_transport_chain) (in which case the ultimate electron acceptor would again be oxygen); or (b) when they were used as a reducing agent in a metabolic reaction.

Comment: Additionally often Glutathione (either oxidized or reduced depending on the reaction) is part of it.

Comment: @Chris thanks, I forgot about glutathione. Of course the diagram could actual be the oxidation of glutathione!